# how to add alertDialog in android?

Tags: android

I am newbie in android. May I Know how to add a alertDialog as confirmation in wifi setting. The alertDialog should consist "yes" for turn on wifi while "no" for close the app.
here is part of coding:

```
> // Check for wifi is disabled
>        if (mainWifi.isWifiEnabled() == false)
>             {   
>                 // If wifi disabled then enable it
>                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "wifi is disabled..making it enabled", 
>                 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>                 
>                 AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
> 
>                 // Setting Dialog Title
>                 alertDialog.setTitle("Confirm...");
> 
>                 // Setting Dialog Message
>                 alertDialog.setMessage("Do you want to turn on your wifi?");
> 
> 
>                 /* i want to add in "YES" and "NO" for the wifi setting
>                  * 
>                  * if yes then turn on
>                  * {
>                  * * mainWifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
>                  * }
>                  * if no then close the app
>                  * {
>                  *    // if this button is clicked, close
>               
>                       mainWifi.this.finish();
>                  * }
>                  * 
>                  * 
>                  * 
>                  * */
>                 // Showing Alert Message
>                 alertDialog.show();
>             }
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is to create a  `AlertDialog Builder` and set a `Title and Message` and map the `Yes/No` to `Positive/Negative` `buttons` with a `dialog click listener` to handle the button click

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Dialog Title")
        .setMessage("Dialog Message")
        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // handle your code to wifi on
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // handle your code to wifi off
            }
        });
    // show the dialog
    builder.show();
```